# Syncfusion JS2 Angular DataGrid Filter on all data?

Tags: angular, syncfusion

I'm Using Syncfusion Js 2 Grid For angular 4, There is a default option for filtering data on the field. But in my case, I have to filter data on full data not on a single column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As from your query, we suspect that would you like to filter the full data source instead of column filters. If so, we have built-in support of Search feature in Grid. In that, we can filter the corresponding value with the whole data source. Please refer to the following Help documentation for more information,

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/grid/searching.html

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/grid/searching.html#initial-search

Regards,
Hariharan